# Undefined variable error in node.tpl.php

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using the Basic theme, and I get the following error when I refresh my site.

> Notice: Undefined variable: unpublished in include() (line 18 of /Users/me/Projects/mysite/httdocs/sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates/node.tpl.php).

The line that is caused the notice is the following one.

```
    <?php if ($unpublished): ?>
      <p class="unpublished"><?php print t('Unpublished'); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </header>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I don't understand this error. How can I fix it?

Comment: This is a bug http://drupal.org/node/1778676

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `if ($node->status == 0)` instead of `if ($unpublished)`.

This may be happening because the variable is not set correctly in a `hook_preprocess_node()` implementation of the theme; you may also want to check the template.php file in your theme for these hooks.